# Moq modify protected on calling void method

Tags: moq, protected, void

I want to use moq a void method and set a value to a protected property when is called.

```
public class MyClass{ public Guid Id {get; protected set; } }

public interface IMyRespository { public void Save(MyClass myClass); }
```

Something like:

```
var moq = new Mock<IMyRespository>();
var my = new MyClass();
moq.Setup(x=>x.Save(my));
```

I want to setup that Id on save is no more a Guid.Empty. 
Save is a void method so no returns, and using:

```
.Callback(() => my = new MyClassImpl(new Guid("..")))
```

is not working..

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to set up the expectation properly. I think what you actually want is to set up the mock so that it accepts any instance of `MyClass`:

```
moq.Setup(x=>x.Save(It.IsAny<MyClass>()));
```

Then, you set up a callback like so:

```
moq.Setup(x=>x.Save(It.IsAny<MyClass>()))
   .Callback((myClassParam) => my = myClassParam);
```

Putting it all together will let you construct a mock that accepts `MyClass` and saves the `MyClass` instance to `my` variable:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test() {
  var moq = new Mock<IMyRespository>();
  MyClass my = null;
  moq.Setup(x=>x.Save(It.IsAny<MyClass>()))
     .Callback((myClassParam) => my = myClassParam);
  var newMyClass = new MyClassImpl(new Guid(".."));
  moq.Object.Save(newMyClass);
  Assert.AreSame(newMyClass, my);
}
```